# Show / hide more than one div:s

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I have two div: s that I want to be able to show and hide.
Today I can show and hide the ones we click on their respective links.

The downside today is that all div opened simultaneously. I want each div is opened by clicking on the respective link. But I do not get to it with my script, does anyone have any idea? '

```
<ul>
    <li class="toogle"><a href="#" class="show_hide" id="plus">Se fler konstnärer +</a></li>
    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
        <li><a href="#">Edvard Munch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ardy Strüwer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ari Behn</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Astrid Gate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cecilie Moi Sindum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vebjørn Sand</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Per Winge</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="toogle"><a href="#" class="show_hide" id="plus">Se fler konstnärer +</a></li>
    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
        <li><a href="#">Teresa Bergerud</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Per Spook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cathrine Maske</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gro Eriksson</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Johan Verde</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>



$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();

   $('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv").slideDown(
         function(){
           $("#plus").text("Se färre konstnärer -")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $(".slidingDiv").slideUp(
       function(){
           $("#plus").text("Se fler konstnärer +")
       }
       );
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there a several reasons

- toggle has been modified in jQuery 1.9: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed
- You're using common selectors like #plus...

Have a look at this:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
   var opener = this;
   $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(function(){
       if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
           $(opener).text("Se fler konstnärer +");
       } else {
           $(opener).text("Se färre konstnärer -");
       }
   });
});
```

And the full runnable version on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42XQD/

Feel free to ask questions when it's unclear :)

Cheers Tobias

Comment: It worked perfectly :)

Thanks for the help, now I just get it to play with my site!

Answer (score 0):

When calling

```
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
```

You hide all div matching the class slidingDiv. If you want to open/hide your divs separatly, you have to identify them by id or different classes.

You can also try to find the div from you "a" element

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: I can not believe I typed it correctly, please see the link?
http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/SvALB/1/

Comment: My mistake, I didn't check the structure of your html document. I've editedthe reply. Check http://jsfiddle.net/SvALB/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the div's different id's. Right now you have given them the same class name and the same id's.

Then you can call the js functions on those id's and not the class names.

Comment: I have changed so I do not have the same id, though, so I do not get to it there after please see link.

http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/SvALB/2/